# Which way is better and secure for Inserting data into Mysql | Sql using Node?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I'm using Nodejs and Express for my project. Which way do you think is better to store data. I'm using two methods to store data but I'm not sure which one is better and secure.

**First Method:**

```
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable (value1,value2) values (?, ?)";
con.query(insertQuery, [value1,value2],(err, rows) => { //Some Code here })
```

but I heard that I must use SQL variables to prevent from SQL injection and actually I'm not sure is it right or not?

**Second Method:**

```
var values = " @v1 :='"+value1"' , @v2 :='"+value2"'";
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO mytable (value1,value2) values (" + values +")";
con.query(insertQuery, (err,rows)=>{  //Some Code here })
```

So what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question - first approach is better because it uses prepared statement, which means that at least your input will be escaped, but there are a lot of cases you need to prevent, some of it:

1. Validate user input
2. Properly encode all symbols, it's the thing why injection is possible

If you don't want to use any ORM's I advice you to use [knex](http://knexjs.org/) , which can work either as sql builder/builder + runner/ builder+runner+mapper. If you are really interested how to build own sql builder, you can read source code of it.